# Кроссбраузерность слайдера

Tags: кроссбраузерность

Как всегда IE доставляет кучу проблем...Вот есть [слайдер](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html)

Захожу с ie на сайт, все работает норм, качаю на камп, и уже не работает... в чем проблема?

**Обновление**

В общем, слайдер в InternetExp работает только на сайте. После того как ставлю у себя, перестает работать. На хосте тоже не работает. http://fmswork.bb777.ru/myproject/avto/index.html

Вот если зайти с InternetExp, то слайдер не работает, а если зайти на их сайт с InternetExp, то слайдер работает. Если скачать его и даже открыть чистый пример (который они дают), то на компьютере уже с Internet Exp не работает.

Comment: Так а что вы качаете?  Если вы хотите локально на компьютере иметь исходники этого слайдера - у вас должно быть: 1)javascript код который может прокручивать с слайда на слайд, 2)файл css стилей и 3)сама верстка с использованием этого слайдера на примере простой странички

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Может быть, потому что в версии jQuery 2.1.1 нет поддержки IE 6-8, попробуйте использовать 1.9.x или 1.11, как на сайте с примером